# Header won't appear when I open the Excel file on SharePoint, because on the VIEW menu only the NORMAL view exists. How can I add Page Layout View

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, footer, header

I have created an Excel file with Header and Footer and I can view the Header and Footer using the Page Layout view when opening the file in my computer.

I upload the same file on SharePoint and open it on SharePoint, I can not see the header and Footer, because only Standard ( or normal) View is available on Excel in SharePoint.

How can I add the Page Layout view to Excel on SharePoint Excel.
I am not the admin and I am not a programmer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open the excel file in SharePoint and edit it in browser, you are actually using Excel Online. Per my knowledge, you cannot modify header and use page layout view in Excel online. You can try to open the file in client application like this:
[image]

It will open the file in your desktop application, which will having the features like header & footer and page layout view.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Armin, Glad to be help. It the reply solves your problem. Would you like to accept it as answer?

Comment: My wish was to add the Page Layout view to Excel on SharePoint Excel. What you offered didn't answer my question, but I accept it as an asnwer, just because you spent time on it and I thank you for that.